# What do schematic symbols (R, C) marked "SHORT" mean?

Tags: schematics, short-circuit

What does it mean when a resistor or capacitor is marked "SHORT" instead of being given a value in a schematic?

[image: resistor marked "SHORT"]

At first this seemed clear to me: it must mean [a 0-ohm resistor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/134360/why-is-there-a-0r-resistor-linking-gnd-and-agnd-in-analog-voltage-reference-circ), something I'm familiar with, although I'm used to seeing them drawn with a value of "0R" or similar. But then I saw this in the same schematic:

[image: capacitor marked "SHORT"]

This I don't understand. My best guess is that it might denote an optional component, where the PCB should have pads for a capacitor (or whatever), but that the pads should be shorted with a cuttable trace or 0-ohm resistor or something. Is that right?

The schematic I'm looking at is the reference design for the output I/V stage for [the ES9028Q2M DAC](https://www.esstech.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/ES9028Q2M_Datasheet_v0.41.pdf) (p. 40):

[image: ES9028Q2M I/V stage]

Comment: It could mean this is a space where they could put a capacitor later if needed, but for now it's shorted.

Comment: Notice also R41: “OPEN”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schematics allow some features like DC blocking or 2-pole low pass filter, but if they are not used then some of these components can't be left out because signal goes through them, so they need to be bypassed with a short.

Which effectively means, a piece of wire for a through-hole component, or maybe a 0 ohm resistor for SMD component.

So in the DC block section, the capacitor needs to be replaced with a short circuit, and to not use the second lowpass filter in the LP filter section, the resistor needs to be shorted out, and the unused capacitor left open (not populated).

Comment: Thanks. Would you say this is somewhat common notation? Have you seen it before? I'm no expert, but I'm used to seeing such optional components given a proper value and then called out as optional in a dotted-line box with a note. I know there is a lot of style variation though when it comes to schematics.

Comment: I don't think I have seen that much, but anyone can use any notation and each company may have internal design rules how to design schematics. I do see the point for this notation, it's compact and conveyes the info that these parts are special. But you can't mark these components optional, as optional means you can leave them out, i.e. open, but in this case, you need to exchange some of the parts to a short circuit. For resistors it's OK to have 0R marked there, but what do you do for capacitor? It's also just as weird to see that say capacitor C1 has value 0R or is a 0R resistor in the BOM.